# Resetting after 3 seconds unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer

I have a board manager in my game, that shows what is happening, for example, if I want to buy a car and you dont have the necessary money in this board appears a message saying "You dont have enough gold".

```
public void setTextMonitor (string mensaje) {
        textScreen = mensaje;
}

public IEnumerator DoTheDance() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // Esperar 3 seconds

    textScreen = "";

}
```

This is my code and it's working properly, when the board shows a message after 5 seconds it's deleted but the board doesn't shows new messages and I dont know why, probably because the couroutine doesn't let setTextMonitor method to work properly dunno.

If you have another idea or other method for doing this, 
I'd be really grateful

Comment: I suggest you edit your question. It is confusing. Say what you expect this code to do and what is happening now. It's hard to understand your problem now

Comment: Update your question and show where are you using this coroutine.

Comment: You probably StartCoroutine(DoTheDance()) multiple times (in a loop for example).

Answer (score 0):

For such behavior really easy to use LeanTween asset. It's free in asset store.

Code will be close to the following:

```
textScreen = "You have not enough of gold";

LeanTween.DelayedCall(5f,()=>{textScreen = "";});
```